# Help me, I bricked my phone, and now it won't boot!

Tags: applications, samsung, rooting, 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-note-3

Samsung Galaxy Note 3, T-Mobile version. Managed to back up all my data, and wiped it. It still won't boot or start, it just remains on the T-Mobile screen. I need help with my phone, I think I triggered a security function on my phone. I rooted with Magisk and it has worked up until now.

My phone just bootloops and it stays on the T-Mobile screen infinitely, as the blue led function indicates something is being written to the memory but I can't figure out what the issue is. I have tried everything, Odin fails to flash a samsung rom, This started when I removed Magisk.zip because it kept crashing and the app became useless so I uninstalled it (Magisk.zip/manager as well). I can't find a stock rom anywhere for the android because it is taken down by Samsung. Someone please point me in a direction to where I can download the rom, maybe samsung will let me flash the rom but since I couldn't find one or the one I have used failed, because ODIN is trash. I decided to render this useless along with my phone. If this doesn't work I will find a way to flash any random rom I can find on to my phone because I don't want it to fail on me.

Comment: You will have to provide us with more details about your situation, what happened before your phone was bricked, what did you do to it? What method you used to root your phone?

Comment: This phone acts crappy, it had crappy performances, apps would crash, couldn't even install apps from the play store because the google play store would crash, I had to keep the old version of the play store but it was difficult because the play store would always update it self to the latest version, so everytime I kept the Play Store on the oldest version it came with, it always would reupdate to the latest version. So then my phone was acting sluggish and slow, mainly because I had a bunch of pusd.us and school accounts of my friends. I rooted my phone in 2020 and it erased all my apps.

Comment: Please, I need help with my phone it is not booting, I have had an even older phone since middle school that was not even as trash as this phone, my sister gave it to me in 2017.

Comment: which partitions exactly you have wiped?

Comment: The main ones, cache and data.

Comment: so you did not wipe any other partition than cache + userdata? do you know the difference between *wipe* and *format* data? have you also tried formatting instead of wipe?

Comment: If I didn't, how do I format data, I have TWRP Recovery on my phone?

Comment: bootloops can have several reasons. most common 1) verified boot - any modifications (like modified recovery) will break boot chain of trust - avb/dm-verity should be disabled for TWRP 2) encryption - verified boot state is used to derive encryption keys. if encryption is broken, formatting userdata is necessary. TWRP does not support samsung encryption, encryption should therefore disabled 1) + 2) = [no-verity-opt-encrypt.zip](https://build.nethunter.com/android-tools/no-verity-opt-encrypt)

Comment: TWRP > Wipe > Format Data > type *yes*

Comment: you can install custom ROM https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4398351

Comment: Now I know what caused my phone to mess up in the first place, I encrypted my phone a long time ago, but I think I rooted too soon after fully decrypting the device. Not a problem for me because all my important files were backed up, but apps got removed as if they were offloaded in the rooting process. So I lost all my google accounts I saved on the phone and other app data. I just need help because my phone seems like it's having problems formatting. Did it mark a partition as read only permanently or is the device becoming faulty? This phone is nine years old.

Comment: I need help because I have zero knowledge with adb, adb fails on my Note 3, ODIN fails also. I managed to flash TWRP using ODIN and then use Magisk Root.

Comment: help with what? stock ROM or custom ROM or Magisk?

Comment: consider after nine years usage the eMMC might weared-out

Comment: No, I figured the problem, the crappy twrp system has been compromised, it won't let me  wipe partiton/cache/or data. I tried looking up why but I got no answer, twrp never gave me issues and now it does. I can't flash or wipe because twrp throws an insane error.

Comment: That sounds like it's going to be a hardware issue, I'm done commenting where else can I go to provide information or get information? Ouch, emmc must be a hardware issue, and that means.... The phone is no good unless you replace the card?

Comment: It is possible to replace but it's not worth it https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004064792620.html